# Is this TIP102 Darlington Transistor Circuit Correct?

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, lithium-ion, darlington

**Objective: Power on Pi Zero by setting pin 13 of Arduino to HIGH.**

I plan on using the Arduino to measure the Li Ion battery voltage and, if well charged (so, say over 4V), then it will pull pin 13 high, which I think will open the circuit for the RPI Zero W.

I've tried to do my research on this but would very much appreciate your views on whether this circuit looks correct. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The TIP102 is an NPN darlington so when its base goes to +5V then its emitter goes to about +3.6V.
When its base goes to +1.4V or less then its emitter goes to 0V.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I've completely misunderstood the transistor. E.g. in my diagram I have the emitted connected to the ground of the Pi, and the collector connected to the ground shared with the battery and the Arduino. But from your reply it sounds like the emitter should have connected to the 5V pin on the Pi (I know, it's the wrong voltage though). Any thoughts on what I should use to switch 5V on for the Pi? E.g. a transistor, a relay, or a load switch IC?

Comment: The collector of the TIP102 should be connected to +5V, not to ground.